# Multiple wordpress projects using local host in my computer

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost

I an using XAMPP and have(created) local host in my computer, but I only can work on one wordpress site now. How would I be able to have multiple wordpress sites under the same local host and can work simultaneously? I tried to add another folder, but failed to do so as I am jsut new to this.

Answer (score 8):

you just need to open a new folder under htdocs and put the wordpress files there .

One folder for each site .

Your folder structure should look like :

```
htdocs 
  ......www.site1.com
        .... wp-admin
        .... wp-content
        .... wp-includes 
             index.php
             all other wp files root directory...
  ......www.site2.com
  ......www.site3.com
```

Or more precisely - like so :

[image: root folders]

where under each "root" folder you will have

[image: wp folder structure]

Then , in the wordpress install, you will need to change the database prefix in `wp-config.php`

```
$table_prefix  = 'wp_site1_';
```

then another one will be

```
$table_prefix  = 'wp_site2_';
```

and so on ,,

```
$table_prefix  = 'wp_my_coolsite_';
```

You can use unlimited installs on one DB.
It is also a good practice to change the  `Authentication Unique Keys and Salts` , but not a must -
I have above 90 myself - just remember to always use a different prefix .

you can acces them with `localhost/www.mysite.com/` ( of course, you do not have to use `www` - it is just a convention i use to help me track the sites on local...

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is virtual hosts, you should be able to configure xampp to respond to any number of addresses on your local machine

Check this out:

http://sawmac.com/xampp/virtualhosts/

Answer (score 0):

I can guess that you have put Wordpress files in the very root of htdocs. I would suggest you to make a folder named wordpress there in htdocs and in the wordpress folder you can make as many folder as you want to create new new development sites.